# Preserve grid focus state even when button left-clicked

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a grid and a button. I want to be able to press *down-arrow* to select a row, then click on the button, then press *down-arrow* to select the next row, then click on the button.

However, when I click on the button, the grid keyboard focus is no longer on the row.

Here's an example. In this picture I have the third row selected. The behavior I want is: I mouse-click on *Press Me*, then press the keyboard down arrow once to select the fourth row. Instead, when I press *down-arrow* the top cell has a frame around it, and when I press it again the top row is selected.

[image: A WPF grid and a button]

How should I go about creating the behavior I need? I've tried editing the code behind to explicitly focus on the grid, but that didn't work.

Here is the complete code for the example.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="DcCharacters">
            <x:XData>
                <Characters xmlns="">
                    <Character HeroName="Catwoman" Identity="Selina Kyle" />
                    <Character HeroName="Batman" Identity="Bruce Wayne" />
                    <Character HeroName="Starman" Identity="Jack Knight" />
                    <Character HeroName="BlueBeetle" Identity="Jaime Reyes" />
                </Characters>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid 
            Grid.Row="0" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DcCharacters}, 
            XPath=//Characters/Character}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            IsReadOnly="True" 
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@HeroName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Identity}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Margin="3,3,3,3" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left">_Press Me!</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the Attached Property [FocusManager.IsFocusScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.isfocusscope.aspx).

By setting it to true on the `StackPanel`, the `Button's` (or other Controls) within it won't steal focus if they are clicked with the mouse. They will work like a Toolbar Button or Menu. You'll still be able to tab to them though.

Here is an example if you have three Buttons instead of one, Cut, Copy and Paste

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
            FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" >
    <Button Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Cut</Button>
    <Button Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Copy</Button>
    <Button Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Paste</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Or in your case, just

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
            FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
    <Button Margin="3,3,3,3" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left">_Press Me!</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `Focusable = "False"` for your Button. It works for me.

```
<Button Margin="3,3,3,3" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Focusable="False">_Press Me!</Button>
```

Comment: +1 because it works. My only issue is that then I can't tab onto that button if I want it to. (Lets see if we can achieve everything :-)

Comment: Only one thing come to my mind - Bind `Focusable` to some property. when you in the table - its false. when you away - its true.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a Hack but it works

```
 private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myDataGrid.SelectedItem != null && e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                DataGridRow dgrow = (DataGridRow)myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myDataGrid.SelectedItem);
                dgrow.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }
        }
```

Comment: +1 Nice. I was trying to override the buttons click handler, but handling the arrow keys through the tunneling event is much smarter.